# Designing the best Meat livestock

Tags: biology, creature-design, fauna, agriculture, farming

I have been wondering what would be the best animal to produce meat, excluding insects and artificial meat.

The following questions are meant to provide ideas:

Would it be better for it to be an Ectotherm or Endotherm? Maybe it would benefit from gigantism or dwarfism. Taking into account broiler chickens are the most efficient (after fish) meat livestock, would a giant bird be better?

Comment: Best... in what terms? Profitability? Nutrition value? Ecological impact? Rule of Cool?

Comment: Hi @Rhomaioi. The [tour] tells us that Stack Exchange is not a discussion forum and the [help/on-topic] discourages brainstorming. Questions asking for help finding the best, worst, most, etc. are notably difficult because superlatives are subjective and circumstantial. Best for a coastal dweller? A forest dweller? Vegetable eaters? Grain eaters? Is it mild? cold? hot? At what altitude? Each of these conditions can (and often do) have a different "best." What's stopping you from naming your creature a brewhaha and declaring it the creature with the most meat? What's the real problem?

Comment: You should probably clarify your question as for the moment it's hard to figure out what you actually want.

Comment: Clearly the answer **has** to be dependent on the societial and cultural look on meat consumption and the terrain the people live in, and how long to keep the animal before eating it. In a society of Hunter Gatherers, the perfect meat animal is the one they can hunt, and that is different from a society of anden dwellers (Guinea pigs) which again is different from medieval europe (pigs) and the levante (NO pigs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without more detail - I cannot give you a definitive answer - but there are some factors that I think we can add:

- Herbivore.

The reason why is that predatory animals are generally less appetizing to eat and they add an increased risk to the farmer, even if they are small.

- Hardy and low-maintenance

This is something where the domestication of animals has had a somewhat negative impact - the fact that we care for our animals (as we should) means that bad genetics that in the wild would be killed off can survive artifically.

- Muscle Growth and Fat growth

An animal that puts on a lot of muscle and fat relatively easy is going to be best - Muscle for Meat, Fat for Flavour.

- Slightly smaller than the average Farmer.

This is a more interesting one - Chickens are, by far, the most populace of Livestock - with there being approx. 135 chickens per Cow. But if we consider the mass of the animal, a Chicken is between 2.5-4 KG, whereas a Cow averages around 510-550 KG at time of slaughter - in terms of raw mass, Cows and Chickens are about equal for the upper-weight of a chicken and Cows easily beating them for the lower weight. A Bigger animal has some advantages - you have to keep an eye on less animals for the same amount of biomass, but also if something goes wrong, it is of greater concern. However...

Cows kill, on average 22 people a year in the US - I did some time helping on a Cattle Farm - they are big, they are strong, they can do stupid things - and if they spook - that is 400-500 KG of Muscle and Bone going at 25 MPH. Oh and they have horns too.

I couldn't find data on Cow-related injuries at a national level - but suffice to say - Cows can do damage.

Chickens on the other hand, whilst having a lot of *injuries* - I couldn't find any data on fatalities.

In short - you want as big an animal as you can get... without it being so big as to kill you.

- Deliciousness

This is a purely subjective one - but if Cows didn't taste so damn yummy and produce milk, we probably wouldn't bother with them. See also Chickens being the most populace.

- Useful by-products

Cows produce Milk and leather (oo-err!), Chickens produce Eggs, Sheep produce Wool, Goats produce milk and escapology etc. If your animal does something else that is another revenue stream for the farmer - it means they can offset some of the cost of rearing the animal over their lifetime which makes it a more appealing notion

- Useful and non-toxic/fatal waste products

So Manure and Chicken poo are common fertilizers - but IIRC they can have issues if not treated properly (I seem to remember Chicken Poo can create fatal levels of gasses and Cow poo can run-off into streams and do bad things) - if you could have a waste product that was good for the soil or garden but with less negative impacts - it would be better - extra revenue stream for the farmer and less impacting to the environment

- Cheap feed

This is probably another big one - the lower-quality the feed that you *can* responsibly, safely and humanely use for an Animal, the easier it is to raise them and turn them into food. Feed varies between 22 percent for total expenses for Beef Cattle to as much as nearly 50 percent for other animals.

- Ease of Slaughter

Yeah - we gonna get messy here - but ultimately you wanna turn an Animal into Meat - you gotta kill it. A docile animal that does not spook easily and does not have a big thick head is going to be easier to kill than one that is skittish and well-armored.